# Jboss 7 - Threads only realeased after 60 seconds

Tags: java, http, jboss7.x, threadpool

After receiving a request, the http thread keeps busy during 60 seconds. Using JConsole, I can see that, during this time, threads stay on:

```
State: RUNNABLE
Stack trace: 
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:721)
org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:359)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:821)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:508)
org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:806)
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:826)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

Why is this? Shouldn't a thread be used and released immediately? This is impacting my server on peak time causing long waits.

Someone can explain me this behavior and how can i disable it or reduce the 60 seconds time?

Thank you all,
Best regards

Comment: I'm not familiar with JBoss, but I wonder if this is in any way related to the keep-alive configuration.

Comment: The keep-alive time is set to 10 seconds. In Jboss, keep alive time states the time that a thread is alive before being destroyed. 
But I have 150 core threads, that never get destroyed and on those, the keep alive time does nothing...
Obrigado Augusto

Answer (score 1):

Your thread is blocking on a socket read operation. Since you are using Java's blocking socket I/O, each connection in the HTTP connection pool must have such a thread associated with it, waiting for a new request.

The solution is to decrease the idle timeout in the HTTP connection pool.

Comment: The idle timeout in the connection pool isn't the same as the keep-alive time? Because changing that time does nothing.
Thanks for the answer...

Comment: Reading your comment under the question, *keep-alive* is a setting on the *thread pool* and pertains to *idle threads*. This thread is not idle because it is actively assigned to the job of reading the socket. I do not know enough about JBoss to be sure which thread pool these are allocated from, if any.

Comment: This threads are allocated from the http thread pool that I call "executor" and that I define to start with 150 core threads. Those threads never get destroyed and should be more than enough. However, because thay stay 60 seconds associated with each request, they turn out not to be enough.

Comment: So your recourse is to configure the *idle HTTP connection timeout*. Unfortunately, without googling I don't know where that's configured.